# Who attacked Gowther when he was brainwashing Dreyfus?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

season 1 episode 18.
I never did understand who attacked or was in Gowther nightmare teller where he was brainwashing Dreyfus and why did "they" attacked or showed up on Gowther brainwashing skill

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it was Fraudrin because he was inside of Dreyfus' mind/body and so he attacked Gowther while he was using nightmare teller. At least that's my theory.